# Can't move the image files with spaces in them using ls and mv commands

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

```
mv $(ls -Art | grep Screen | tail -1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g') ~/Pictures/Screenshots/
```

This is my command to move all the screenshots from home directory to some other direct

```
mv: cannot stat 'Screenshot\': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'from\': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '2017-09-21\': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '19-45-54.png': No such file or directory
```

Output of :

```
ls |grep Screen | tail -1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

is:

```
Screenshot\ from\ 2017-09-21\ 19-45-54.png
```

Please help me do this. I've planned on running this command using cron but its not working.

Also I do understand that the easier way is to use an application to just save the screenshots to that folder itself but I don't want that. 
Thank you

Comment: Don't pipe `ls` commands. Instead use `find` with `exec` to process the files found by `find`. Something like `find ./ -type f -name "Screen*" -exec mv "{}" ~/Pictures/Screenshots/ \;`

Comment: Do you want `mv Screen* ~/Pictures/Screenshots` ?